# Are you ethically obligated to download this?

Tags: ethics

There's an app that gives money to charity depending on how much you run. You can choose between dozens of organizations that help stop hunger, help the homeless, cure cancer, provide vaccines to poor people, build schools, etc. Now that you know this exists, are you ethically obligated to download and use it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has nothing to do with philosophy or any SE, and seems to be a form of spam.

Comment: I'm guessing the question is about a hypothetical app, and is asking about the ethical implications of downloading such an app. As asked, though, I don't really see any interesting philosophical question here. If there were such a thing that only caused good things to happen, then yes you should do it.

Answer (score 2):

First off, obligated is a very powerful word, which almost certainly will yield a "no" answer to your question.  That being said, the question of what is ethical is one whose answers are not fully agreed upon.  At the very least, some suggest it is the "good you do" while some suggest it is "how you do it."  That debate alone will limit the ethical obligations.

Also, there is no reason to believe on is ethically obliged to do any particular charity.  At best, if one chooses their base set of assumptions carefully, they may be obliged to offer charity in general, but the particular means is not essential.

You could argue that "you should be ethically obliged to make it easier to do ethical things," but that argument is really hard.  All you're doing is removing the activation energy of the charity process -- your ethical obligation for charity is unchanged by the presence of a tool to make it easier, except by a tiny fraction (most of the process of donating to charity is the hours of work it takes to make the money.  The 30 seconds it takes to donate is a trivial part of the charity process from an effort perspective)

Answer (score 0):

> There's an app that gives money to charity depending on how much you run. You can choose between dozens of organizations that help stop hunger, help the homeless, cure cancer, provide vaccines to poor people, build schools, etc. Now that you know this exists, are you ethically obligated to download and use it?

No. Because too many charities have a hundred million quid in the bank already, and a whole lot of fatcats on fat salaries purring around in chauffer-driven cars splashing the cash like it's their personal fiefdom. And some of these people  react with horror at the thought of actually *solving* the problems they peddle and pimp to make their easy living. So no, you are not "ethically obligated" to download it. Not at all.